# How to copy a local file to all nodes in (an AWS) cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, distributed-computing, scp

Starting with a 10MB on a local computer, we'd like to copy it to all 100 nodes on an *existing* cluster on AWS, *without restarting the cluster*. This cluster has 1 "master" node; the rest are "Task" and "Core".

Current solution (below) seems ad-hoc, are there better ones? Once the file is on master, I'm wondering if a tool like Spark could permanently copy this file to all other nodes via broadcast...

Current solution:
Get all 100 dns values for the 100 nodes as a list. Use this list in a script (e.g. bash) and execute an scp command 100 times.

Comment: What is there in a file. And how you are going to use the file. Is this a one time activity or you need to copy it for every application.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to copy it to all nodes? (There might be an alternate solution using HDFS.)

Comment: it's a jar file that each node needs to access at runtime. hdfs might help :-)